# Can mvn package produce Android .apk from clean slate?

Tags: android, maven-3

I would like to be able to check out my Android app project and do "mvn package" and get an .apk without having to:

1. manually "android update sdk", and
2. manually sticking jars in my local maven repository.

Is there a plugin (or plugins) that can do this?

Currently, I have to first do various "android update sdk" and then use https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer to stick jar files into my local repo for Maven to find them.

(This seems like a question that should have been asked many times before, but my search-fu fails me.)

EDIT: Sorry, my bad. I should know by now that no question without source code is complete. Yes, there are maps dependencies. Also, as far as I can tell, there is a rather limited selection of jars. For example, there seem to be no 4.0.3 jar here: http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android%22

My current dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>maps</artifactId>
        <version>15_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are targeting Honeycomb, this shouldn't be necessary. The SDK libraries for recent versions are already available in the central repository. Even the SDK deployer README says so:

> ATTENTION! Currently some android.jar artifacts are available in Maven
>   central and unless you use maps or usb related dependencies, android
>   3.0+, the compatibility library jar files or insist on using the original jar files from the local SDK install, you might not need this
>   tool anymore.

Comment: You don't need the exact same version (4.0.3, etc) as long as it has the same API level. As for the maps jar, it is proprietary and probably won't be deployed to central. You can, of course, use your own private repository initialized with all the jars you need. Then they will be fetched automatically and you won't need to use the SDK deployer, etc.